# Use data.frame/tibble to specify scale_x_continous breaks in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got the following plot:

```
require(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

vary_1 <- c(
    exp(rnorm(250,5,1)),
    rnorm(250,10,10),
    exp(rnorm(250,20,1)),
    exp(rnorm(250,30,1)))


vary_2 <- c(
    rep('A',250),
    rep('B',250),
    rep('C',250),
    rep('D',250))

data_frame(vary_1,vary_2) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(vary_1,color = vary_2,fill = vary_2))+
    geom_density()+
    facet_wrap(~vary_2,scales = 'free')
```

I'd like to specify the scale breaks using values from a `data_frame`. I get these values like this:

```
p <- data_frame(vary_1,vary_2) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(vary_1,color = vary_2,fill = vary_2))+
    geom_density()+
    facet_wrap(~vary_2,scales = 'free')

q <- layer_data(p)
q %>%
    group_by(PANEL) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(x), funs(min, max))

  PANEL   min   max
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1      8.53  16.1
2 2      7.55  13.8
3 3      4.50  12.4
4 4      9.53  12.2
5 5     10.0   12.1
6 6      8.12  11.2
7 7      8.19  11.2
8 8      6.46  10.4
9 9      4.41  10.3
```

My solution is to `split` `q` into a `list` and use that to specify the breaks, but `ggplot` doesn't like that and gives an error. How can I use a `data_frame` to specify breaks in `ggplot` `facets`? Or is there a better way?

```
breaks_ls <- q %>% 
    group_by(PANEL) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(x), funs(min, max)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(PANEL,min,max) %>% 
    split(.,.$PANEL)

break_values <- map(breaks_ls,function(x){
    as.numeric(x[1,])
})


data_frame(vary_1,vary_2) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(vary_1,color = vary_2,fill = vary_2))+
    geom_density()+
    facet_wrap(~vary_2,scales = 'free')+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = map(breaks_ls,function(x){
        as.numeric(x[1,])
    }))
```

Gives this error

```
Error in x[finite & x < range[1]] <- NA_real_ : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Comment: I understand if you want to specify some other x limits to each panel. But why do you have to use the same breaks that you derived from the same plot?

Comment: FWIW, this seems to be a feature request. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/187

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to do it with the [`patchwork` package](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork). But this approach might be more laborious.

This approach works as follows:

1. Make a list, `df_list` of the plots using `split`.
2. Extract the objects and store them into the global environment with `list2env(df_list, globalenv())`
3. Modify each plot as needed.
4. Use `patchwork` package to patch your plots.

---

```
library(patchwork)

df <- data.frame(vary_1, vary_2)

df_list <- df %>% 
  split(.$vary_2) %>%
  map(~ggplot(.,aes(vary_1))+
        geom_density())

list2env(df_list, globalenv())

# I used other values, but you can adjust to your use case
A <- A + xlim(0, 2000)
B <- B + xlim(-10, 30)
C <- C + xlim(0, 2e9)
D <- D + xlim(0, 1e14)

(A + B) / (C + D)
```

[image]